# How do I get the selected text from custom spinner?

Tags: android, spinner

How do I get the selected text from a custom spinner?

I have spinner contains name Raju and Rani; if I select "Raju," then "Raju" has to print and if I select "Rani," then "Rani" has to print.

```
spinnerName = (Spinner)m_view.findViewById(R.id.spinner_name);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapterName = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item) {

                @Override
                public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                    View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                    if (position == getCount()) {
                        ((TextView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText("");
                        ((TextView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setHint(getItem(getCount()));



                          String  spinnertext = spinnerCity.getSelectedItem().toString();   
                        System.out.println("spinner" +spinnertext);


                    }

                    return v;
                }       

                @Override
                public int getCount() {
                    return super.getCount()-1; // you dont display last item. It is used as hint.
                }

            };



            adapterCity.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            adapterCity.add("Raju");
            adapterCity.add("Rani");             
            adapterCity.add("name"); //This is the text that will be displayed as hint.
                spinnerName.setAdapter(adapterName);
        spinnerName.setSelection(adapterName.getCount());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you already populate your spinner . now write this code for get selected text from spinner

```
spinnerName.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String text = spinnerName.getSelectedItem().toString();
            }
}
```

text contain selected text .. now you can use it as your logic.
hope it works ...

Answer (score 0):

Make use on setOnItemSelectedListener. It will return you the selected item of the spinner

Example

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this); 
... 
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,long id) { 
Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "OnItemSelectedListener : " + parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
}
```